# C++ Winapi while-loop workaround?

Tags: c++, winapi

So, I have this ordinary while loop (as shown) and while my program is running inside the while loop for an extended period of time, the window becomes unresponsive, saying "blah blah blah isn't responding." Well... I know in WinAPI I should use the SetTimer() function and WM_TIMER, but guess what! I'm programming for fun this time, and I would like to know if there is a workaround... such as putting something inside my while loop that will keep it "responsive". I am not trying to be destructive.

Here is the Code:

```
while (battleupdate == 1)
{
    RECT wrect;
    wrect.left   = 0;
    wrect.right  = 570;
    wrect.top    = 0;
    wrect.bottom = 432;

    if (FILLRECT == 0){
    FillRect(hdc, &wrect, (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH));
    cout << "battleupdated" << endl; FILLRECT = 1; }


    /*OPPONENT STATS*/        
    if (1 == 1) {   stringstream stream; stream << opname << "            ";        
        TextOut (hdc, 20, 50, stream.str().c_str(), 12); }
    //if (1 == 1) {   stringstream stream; stream << itemslot4name << "        ";        
        //TextOut (hdc, 465, 188, stream.str().c_str(), 12); }
    //if (1 == 1) {   stringstream stream; stream << itemslot4effect << "   ";        
        //TextOut (hdc, 465, 204, stream.str().c_str(), 4); }

        battleupdate = 1; 

        //I DON'T CARE IF MY DELAY CODE IS LAME YES I KNOW ABOUT SLEEP().
        while (delay > 0)
        {
            delay -= 1;
        }
        if (delay == 0)
        {
            delay = resetdelay;
        }
    }
```

Is what I'm asking possible?

I appreciate any answers, even "Nope can't do that, You better use WM_TIMER!"
so thanks in advance for answers!

- Operating system: windows 7 ultimate
- Compiler: Dev-C++
- Other: using winapi

Comment: actually, that was needed! thanks sayem.

Comment: If you are a UI thread you need to process messages. `WM_TIMER` is not the issue, you need to call either `GetMessage()` or `PeekMessage()` in your loop and dispatch the messages.

Comment: as I said, I don't know much, or even what that means . . Please Tell me!!!

Comment: There are no workarounds, (not even WM_TIMER), either you need to process messages, or you need to do this work on a separate thread.

Comment: john i didn't mean inside this loop wmtimer, i meant i could use a loop with wmtimer.

Comment: jonathan potter thats pretty much the answer.

Comment: JONATHAN JONATHAN!!!! ok i got PeekMessage() but give me an example of DispatchMessage() !!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know, you should use timers to handle your logic...

But if you really do not want to do this, you can use "DoEvents" do keep the window "responsive"...

```
void DoEvents()
{
  MSG msg;
  BOOL result;

  while ( ::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE ) )
  {
    result = ::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (result == 0) // WM_QUIT
    {                
      ::PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);
      break;
    }
    else if (result == -1)
    {
       // Handle errors/exit application, etc.
    }
    else 
    {
      ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
      ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }
}
```

And in your while-loop you just need to call "DoEvents" periodically...

Comment: Why call `PeekMessage()` with `PM_NOREMOVE` followed by `GetMessage()`?

Comment: Because `Getmessage` will block if there is no message!

Comment: The message is removed if you use the `PM_REMOVE` flag.

Comment: But how do you distungish between WM_QUIT and no message??? Check in the message? For me this solution works and is better...

Comment: `PeekMessage()` retrives `WM_QUIT` just like any other message. `if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) { }`

Comment: This link might be a bit old, but still [excellent reading on this topic](http://www.flounder.com/badprogram.htm). Don't write defective programs.